# Error in glossaries.sty package

Tags: glossaries

Can any one tell what error I did in the following coding:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

Test \gls{$\sum$} or \gls{$\prod$}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \DOTSB
l.7 Test \gls{$\sum$}
                      or \gls{$\prod$}
?
```

Please suggest what went wrong in my coding...

Comment: You can't use special characters (such as `$`) in the labels.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

I think you've misunderstood the way the `glossaries` package works. You have to first define the terms (or symbols or whatever). Each term is identified by a unique label, which shouldn't contain any special characters. This label is used as a reference in commands like `\gls`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sum}{name={$\sum$},text={\sum},description={summation}}
\newglossaryentry{prod}{name={$\prod$},text={\prod},description={product}}

\begin{document}

Test $\gls{sum}$ or $\gls{prod}$.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sum}{name={\ensuremath{\sum}},description={summation}}
\newglossaryentry{prod}{name={\ensuremath{\prod}},description={product}}

\begin{document}

Test \gls{sum} or \gls{prod}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Both methods produce:

[image: Test ∑ or ∏.]